# Moodle Block Upload

Tags: php, plugins, block, moodle

I am currently developing a Moodle Plugin. I have followed the documentation for setting up a moodle block, and installing it. However after I have put the plugin file into the block folder of my Moodle, it does not register it, and I am unable to install it. Can someone tell me if my code/ file structure is incorrect or where I am going wrong please?

Thanks in advance

[File structure of Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLgsY.png)

```
x<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
//Block class Definition
    class block_QEIMS extends block_list {
//init method that gives values to any clas member variables that need instantiating
public function init() {
        $this->    title = get_string('QEIMS', 'block_QEIMS');
}

public function get_content() {
if ($this->content !== null) {
  return $this->content;
    }

$this->content         =  new stdClass;
$this->content->text   = array();
$this->content->icons  = array();
$this->content->footer = 'Footer here...';

$this->content->items[] = html_writer::tag('a', 'School', [href=>'School.php']);
$this->content->items[] = html_writer::tag('b', 'Teacher', [href=>'Teacher.php']);
$this->content->items[] = html_writer::tag('c', 'Pupils', [href=>'Pupils.php']);

return $this->content;
  }

   public function specialization() //Loads congifuration data
      { 
if (isset($this->config)) 
{
    if (empty($this->config->title)) 
    {
        $this->title = get_string('defaulttitle', 'block_qeims');            
    } else 
    {
        $this->title = $this->config->title;
    }

    if (empty($this->config->text)) 
    {
        $this->config->text = get_string('defaulttext', 'block_qeims');
    }    
}
}
    public function instance_allow_multiple() //This method allows the         user to add multiple versions of this block
    {
      return true;
    }

    function preferred_width() 
    {
      // Default case: the block wants to be 180 pixels wide
      return 180;
    } 
    function refresh_content() 
    {
        // Nothing special here, depends on content()
        $this->content = NULL;
        return $this->get_content();
    }
        /**
 * Allow the block to have a configuration page
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
        public function has_config() {
        return true;
        }
    public function instance_config_save($data, $nolongerused = false) //
    {
        $data = stripslashes_recursive($data);
        $this->config = $data;
        return set_field('block_instance', 
                         'configdata',
                          base64_encode(serialize($data)),
                         'id', 
                         $this->instance->id);
    }

      }

  // Here's the closing bracket for the class definition
    ?>
    <p> this is a test </p>

<form>
    <input type="button" name="Teacher" value="Teacher"> //These buttons are tests
</form>
<form>
    <input type="button" name="Pupil" value="Pupil"> //These buttons are tests
</form>
<form>
    <input type="button" name="School" value="School"> //These buttons are tests
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to create the

> block_QEUMS.php

file in the directory tree.

Comment: Hi @icsbcn thanks for your interest and help. I have renamed my index file to block_qeims, which is where all the code that I have posted above

Comment: Hi @borson89. If my answer was helpful for you, could you mark it as "accepted"?

After move all code to `block_qeims.php`, was the result ok?